# Why IntelliJ IDEA uses outdated version of Maven plugins by default?

Tags: intellij-idea

I recently installed fresh version of IDEA (2018.2.5), created maven project using built-in IDEA feature for this, and during compilling my TestNG tests I noticed this:

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ GoogleSearchTest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\GoogleSearchTest\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ GoogleSearchTest ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\GoogleSearchTest\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ GoogleSearchTest ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\GoogleSearchTest\target\surefire-reports
```

If you check mvnrepository site you will see that version of plugins is outdated, it is from 2012-2013, don't get why it is like that ...

Comment: What plugin version is set in your pom.xml?

Comment: y.bedrov, compiler and resources plugins where not specified, surefire was set to old version. I got it, I can just specify desired version in pom.xml, and this version will be downloaded and ready to use. Thank you.